# How to remove the cancelled migration from the db folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to remove a migration from my application.

I have a migration file `20141105030942_removedate_fromexpense.rb`

the class file for the migrations is

```
class RemovedateFromexpense < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   remove_column :expenses, :date, :date
  end
end
```

When I give this command:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141105030942
```

I get the following error:

```
== 20141105030942 RemovedateFromexpense: reverting ============================
-- add_column(:expenses, :date, :date)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this migration was canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: date: ALTER TABLE "expenses" ADD "date" date/home/sumyvps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

db:migrate:status for migration file is as below
up     20141105030942  Removedate fromexpense
```

Has anyone an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run this migration in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A common task is to rollback the last migration. For example, if you made a mistake in it and wish to correct it. Rather than tracking down the version number associated with the previous migration you can run:

```
rake db:rollback
```

This will rollback the latest migration, either by reverting the change method or by running the down method. If you need to undo several migrations you can provide a STEP parameter:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```

### will revert the last 3 migrations.

First Run:

```
rails generate migration RemoveDateFromExpense date:date
```

then `rake db:migrate`
Hope this help!

Comment: `rake db:rollback STEP=1` to only go back one step.

Comment: @TheChamp `rake db:rollback` only goes back one step.  `STEP=` is only necessary when you want to rollback the past few migrations

Comment: Thanks for yours, hadn't realised the type was supported in `remove_column` on rails 4.  That's nice.  Deleted answer as not relevant.

Comment: This is my second last migration and I dont want to rollback my last migration

Comment: @Sumy you could add another migration that does the opposite of your posted one?

Comment: @Sumy now see my answer.

Comment: sorry i meant to say rake db:rollback also gives the same error

Comment: first run:  rails generate migration RemoveDateFromExpense date:date

Comment: then:   rake db:migrate

Comment: @Jazib Bashir Thanks it worked...and I understood what exactly the problem was... :)

Comment: It seems that as I had changed the migration class file name, the migration did not work, and it was adding the column instead of removing the column from the table...so by generating the migration for removing the column again it worked fine... :)

Comment: if my answer helps than expect it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the column type in your migration file. Just the name of the table and the column is enough to remove the column from the table.

Edit your migration file to:

```
class RemovedateFromexpense < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   remove_column :expenses, :date
  end
end
```

And then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This should do the work.